# Argument 'SpecificGroupType1' is not assignable to parameter type 'Group<IItem>'

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to put together an architecture like this:

- Section

  - Group

    - Item

      - Attribute
      - Attribute
  - Group

    - Item

      - Attribute
      - Attribute
- Section

  [...]

I'm then trying instantiate this architecture like this:

```
var sections = new List<ISection>
{
    new Section("Section Header", new List<Group<IItem>>
    {
        new SpecificGroupType1(token, "GroupName")
    }
};
```

The SpecificGroupType1 then spins up a new list of the appropriate IItem type.

I'm getting the following error, though:

```
Argument SpecificGroupType1 is not assignable to parameter type Group<IItem>
```

I'm not quite sure why, though, because SpecificGroupType1 inherits from Group.

The full architecture looks like this (I omitted the IAttribute stuff, because the issue I'm running into happens before IAttribute stuff even gets involved):

**Section.cs**

```
public interface ISection { // Stuff }

public class Section : ISection
{
    public Section(string sectionName, IList<Group<IItem>> groups)
    {
        Name = sectionName;
        Groups = groups;
    }
}
```

**Group.cs**

```
public interface IGroup { // Stuff }

public abstract class Group<T> : IGroup where T : IItem
{
    protected Group(JToken token, string groupName)
    {
        Name = groupName;
        Items = new List<IItem>();

        foreach (var itemToken in Token.Children())
        {
            Items.Add((Item)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), itemToken);
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; internal set; }
    public JToken Token { get; internal set; }

    protected IList<IItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**SpecificGroupType1.cs**

```
public class SpecificGroupType1 : Group<SpecificItemType1>
{
    public SpecificGroupType1(JToken token, string groupName) : base(token, groupName) {}

    // Stuff
}
```

**Item.cs**

```
public interface IItem { // Stuff }

public abstract class Item : IItem
{
    protected ConfigurationItem(JToken token)
    {
        Attributes = new List<IAttribute>();
        Token = token;
    }

    public IList<IAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
    public JToken Token { get; set; }
}
```

**SpecificItemType1.cs**

```
public class SpecificItemType1 : Item
{
    public SpecificItemType1(JToken token) : base(token) {}

    // Stuff
}
```

Comment: One problem I see in your code is you have `IGroup<IItem>`, however the declaration of `IGroup` has no generic parameters.  That will fail to compile, unless there's an additional generic interface definition somewhere.

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo. That's actually IList<Group<IItem>> in my code.

Comment: Got a definition for SpecificItemType1? Is it inheriting from Item?

Comment: Just added the definition. Yep, it inherits from Item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, this is a problem with your generic parameters.  Consider this simplified example.

```
// does not compile
Group<IItem> g = new SpecificGroupType1(token, "GroupName");

// does compile
Group<SpecificItemType1> g = new SpecificGroupType1(token, "GroupName");
```

The problem is that `SpecificGroupType1` implements the class `Group<SpecificItemType1>`, which is **not** the same as `Group<IItem>`.  If you want to be able to use more derived generic parameter types this way, you need to use a covariant generic parameter declaration.  In C#, that's only possible on interfaces, not classes, so you may need to refactor a bit.  It would be something like this.

```
interface IGroup<out T> : IGroup where T: IItem {
    // declarations
}
```

Note the `out` keyword.